# Unable to create Bridging header in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I am planning to add two files from objective C, [PendulumView.h and PendulumView.m] to swift. But if I try to create bridging header, I am unable to create Bridging header. Xcode doesn't ask me "Would you like to create bridging header?". That dialog box also not appeared. If I proceed and I imported my header file, I am receiving error.

(Command + N) -> iOS -> Source -> Objective-C/Header file. No Bridging header is creating. Automatically, .h or .m file is created.

#### pendulum_header.h file

```
#ifndef pendul_test_pendul_Header_h
#define pendul_test_pendul_Header_h

#import "PendulumView.h"

#endif
```

#### ViewController file

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var pendul_object = PendulumView() //Error Receiving. Unresolved Identifier PendulumView

}
```

Screen shot is below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference types defined in Objective C Library from Swift Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064722/reference-types-defined-in-objective-c-library-from-swift-application)

Comment: Same issue,, that dialog box is not appearing. I have tried another way, Same issue happening. Bridging header file is not creating.

Comment: read to the bottom of my answer there.

Comment: Still now not clear. Can u guide me? according to my output.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in my answer there, all the way through the entire answer? What part is unclear?

Comment: As a final note about the trouble you're having importing the library's header file into the file you want to use as the bridging header: it is necessary that you actually obtain a copy of the header file for the library you're using. You can't just put the .a file in your project. You need the .a and any/all corresponding .h files that go with that library. So make sure you've got the .h files in your project along with your bridging header properly set up.

Comment: this line?? i couldn't understand

Comment: You can ignore this. You're not importing a compiled .a file.

Comment: Remaining thing, i had follow. I am getting error.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain exactly where you are getting stuck or exactly what error you get...

Comment: 1. I Imported two files, [.h, .m]

Comment: 2. I created header file. [Bridging header dialog box not appeared]

Comment: 3. Swift Complier, I edited like this "/Users/xxxxxyyyy/Desktop/POC_PROJ/FULL_Swift/pendul_test/pendul_test-Bridging-Header.h"

Comment: 4. In that header file [pendul_test-Bridging-Header.h], I imported that .h file [#import "PendulumView.h"]

Comment: 5. In mainViewController, in viewDidLoad method, I created instance like this, [var pendul_obj = PendulumView(), I am receiving error here, "Unresolved identifier, Pendulum"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I attached the [sample video](https://www.sendspace.com/file/s3w1yf) for how to create the `Objective-C Bridging Header`, if you need the more answer or second option u need **Henny Lee** answer also fine.

Comment: link is broken. Please put a text representation of the answer. Links tend to get broken

Answer (score 2):

Mistake is completely my side.

What I did?

1. Open new project -> Imported that .h and .m file.
2. Right Click -> New File -> "iOS -> Source -> Objective-C.m"
3. .m file has been created, but bridging header not created.

What should do?

1. Open new project
2. Right Click -> New File -> "iOS -> Source -> Objective-C.m"
3. Bridging header has been created with .m file.
4. Then, Import that .h and .m file.

Answer (score 0):

Try go to your project settings. In the `Build Settings` tabs go to the search field and search for `bridging`. In the following search result you should see: **Swift Compiler - Code Generation** with a setting for `Objective-C Bridging Header`. Change the value to your project path (where your project files are stored in) and you should be good to go.

Comment: At the top left corner, theres a button for `Basic` and `All`. Press the `All` button and it should show.

Comment: ya got it. How to find project path??

Comment: One easy way to do it is: click on a random (swift) file in your project. In your utilities panel (with all the options etc) there should be two icons. Click on the left icon looking like a document if it's not already selected. In the second section there's the full path of that file. Use that path (minus the file name you've clicked).

Comment: Objective C Bridging Header  /Users/xxxxxyyyy/Desktop/POC_PROJ/FULL_Swift/pendul_test/