# Xcode 6/CocoaPods 0.36 - adding Swift bridging header to project Build Settings manually

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I've read a bunch of articles on adding a Swift bridging header to an Obj-c project:

- [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)
- [Bohemian Polymorph](https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/)
- [SwiftCast](https://swiftcast.tv/articles/manually-add-bridging-header)

Using CocoaPods 0.36, I should see the `Swift Compiler` sections appear in `Build Settings` but they aren't? I search in the box for `Swift` or `Bridging` and nothing shows up. And I can't add a new Swift file to the project in this situation because I'm writing some reusable installation steps for a project (having the end user create a blank swift file and delete it after the fact is pretty janky).

What's the proper way to manually add a bridging header and configure the Build settings when using CocoaPods? What am I missing?

*Bonus Points*: I'm ultimately going to be scripting this. If you have an idea of how to do it programmatically, that's even better!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference types defined in Objective C Library from Swift Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064722/reference-types-defined-in-objective-c-library-from-swift-application)

Comment: @nhgrif no, I already explained why I can't do that. I've made it **bold** in the question so you can read it more clearly.

Comment: Can't do what?  Did you read the answer?  The first part says that Xcode will offer to make it for you *but* the entire rest of the answer explains **exactly** what you're asking--how to manually add a bridging header.

Comment: @nhgrif and that doesn't show up in Xcode 6, as I indicated in the first part of my paragraph.

Comment: What doesn't show up?

Comment: The Swift Compiler sections. There's nothing between `Static Analyser` and `User-Defined`

Comment: Then your project isn't compiling any Swift files and you don't need a bridging header.  That section shows up if and only if you have `.swift` files to compile.

Comment: There are swift files in a CocoaPod I'm building - they're included and I can see them in the `Development Pods` folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76103/discussion-between-nhgrif-and-remus).