# How would I fix my error for Bridging Header in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Im adding an ad network called StartApp and I messed up my bridging header in my build settings in xcode swift. I get an error saying this. Why is this happening?

```
 <unknown>:0: error: bridging header '/Users/welch/Desktop/DONT DELETE/My Project/My_Project/My_Project-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference types defined in Objective C Library from Swift Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064722/reference-types-defined-in-objective-c-library-from-swift-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the build settings of your your app target find section **Swift Compiler - Code Generation** and delete the **Objective-C Bridging Header** or replace it with your new header filename.

Answer (score 0):

If your following the steps of naming your bridging header (Projectname-Bridging-Header.h->spaces replaced by '-') , then You have to make sure , pointing  to the right Path of you bridging-header file in Target->Buildsettings->Objective-c bridging header ,,I mean make sure to include parent directories  if any!